# Efficient way to continually run interval scheduling algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, greedy

I have a problem where I need to repeatedly run interval scheduling algorithm on a set of inputs that are streaming.

For example imagine you have a stream of unsorted data for which you continuously get values over time. At the beginning let say I start with 8 intervals, I run interval schedule algorithm to get an output.

Following is the code for the interval scheduling algorithm:

```js
    class Job {
        constructor(start, finish, name) {
            this.start = start;
            this.finish = finish;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    function intervalScheduling(jobs) {

        jobs.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.finish - b.finish;
        })

        let jobsSelected = [];
        jobsSelected.push(jobs[0]);

        let lastJob = jobs[0];

        for(let i=0; i<jobs.length;i++) {
            if (jobs[i].start >= lastJob.finish) {
                jobsSelected.push(jobs[i]);
                lastJob = jobs[i];
            }
        }

        console.log(jobsSelected);
    }

    let jobs = [
        new Job(0, 6, "a"),
        new Job(1, 4, "b"),
        new Job(3, 5, "c"),
        new Job(3, 8, "d"),
        new Job(4, 7, "e"),
        new Job(5, 9, "f"),
        new Job(6, 10, "g"),
        new Job(8, 11, "h"),
    ];

    intervalScheduling(jobs);
```

I need to repeatedly call     `intervalScheduling(jobs);` with new set of jobs every one second.

Since I will need to sort each time, the run time of the algorithm over the course of the program would be O(n^2 log n) because the runtime of the interval schedule algorithm is O(n log n) times the number of times I run it over time. Is there a way to use a better algorithm for this and get the run time to be lower?

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by 'scheduling' the intervals?

Comment: You could represent dates as timestamps and use them in a sorted data structure, like a red-black tree, where you can insert new elements in O(lg n).

Comment: @orlp I edited the question and added some code to clarify that a bit. It just means 'output'. I edited the text to remove it to avoid confusing it with the name of the algorithm.

Comment: @user3312156 Do the jobs that didn't get selected stay for the next round? Your code only shows one set of jobs being scheduled.

Comment: @orlp Yes they would need to stay. I will need to also remove the jobs that were output and then run the algorithm on both leftover items and new set of items that I received. Also would it make a difference if we were to use the left over jobs vs not use them?

Comment: can you describe __what__ is interval scheduling. You implemented something but it does not necessarily mean what is expected... What prevents us from just taking a single job among the given jobs ? What if if we output two jobs when 7 could be outputted, etc...

Comment: @grodzi Interval scheduling is an algorithm. [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling)


and (sample implementation in java that I found)
[https://github.com/SleekPanther/interval-scheduling/blob/master/IntervalScheduling.java]

Each time we run the algorithm, we are trying to schedule as many jobs as we can from the available list of jobs.

Comment: It looks like the previous link I posted was wrong and I cant edit anymore, posting again
https://github.com/SleekPanther/interval-scheduling/blob/master/IntervalScheduling.java and simpler [explanation](https://github.com/SleekPanther/interval-scheduling)